# I can't set sticky footer

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set up sticky footer, but still something goes wrong, it just doesnt want to be under, and it goes on content when I resize the window. I tried with `position: absolute, bottom: 0` then `margin-top` etc, and I tried with  but it also doesnt work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/swynw/4/

Comment: if you set `position: absolute;bottom: 0;` to your `<footer>` element, as you mentioned, it sticks to the bottom.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem, sticky footer usually is referred to a div that sticks to the bottom of the page, but what you want is needs to have fixed position on bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `body` and `html` to `height:100%`, set your `footer` to `position: fixed, bottom: 0`.

Also remove the style `height: 100%` from `#content`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    footer{
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your footer `div` is has `footer` ID:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    $("#footer").stickyFooter();
});
// sticky footer plugin
(function ($) {
    var footer;

    $.fn.extend({
        stickyFooter: function (options) {
            footer = this;

            positionFooter();

            $(window)
                .scroll(positionFooter)
                .resize(positionFooter);

            function positionFooter() {
                var docHeight = $(document.body).height() - $("#sticky-footer-push").height();
                if (docHeight < $(window).height()) {
                    var diff = $(window).height() - docHeight;
                    if ($("#sticky-footer-push").length < 0) {
                        $(footer).before('<div id="sticky-footer-push"></div>');
                    }
                    $("#sticky-footer-push").height(diff);
                }



            }
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$("#footer").stickyFooter();
```

Comment: although interesting post, the OP has not asked for js solution.

Comment: But this works as a sticky footer solution.